# Cypress stuck with Chrome stable 80

Tags: angular, google-chrome, ubuntu, jenkins, cypress

While running cypress 3.8.0, as part of our CI, via Chrome Stable version 80 Cypress gets stuck, no error indication provided but halted run on the first scenario.

It worked well with version `79.0.3945.130-1`

How can I progress in diagnosing, overcoming this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had this issue this morning, was able to resolve the issue by upgrading to cypress 3.8.3